# Modify WPDownloadManager Button Link Color

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change the color of the Wordpress Download Manager (WPDownloadManager) plugin's link-template-button.
It doesn't seem to have it's own color style for the colored button, which is problematic, since it uses the primary link color of the rest of the site.

The primary link color of the site has a red-ish color, while my download button is blue.
I want the download-button text to be white (to achieve white on blue) instead of the current red on blue.

These are the css-classes used by the button: `wpdm-download-link wpdm-download-locked btn btn-primary`

I tried to add CSS additions as follows (none of which are working):

```
.wpdm-download-link.wpdm-download-locked.btn.btn-primary a:link {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

```
.wpdm-download-link a:link {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

```
a.wpdm-download-link:link {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

...and other combinations of of these classes.

I also tried for a:visited, a:hoover etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the set primary link color you select on the `Customize > Colours > Primary Link Color` uses a #content attribute, so in order to change the color for all WPDownloadManager, you need to add Additional CSS like so:

```
#content a.wpdm-download-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

or if you want different colors/styles e.g for link and hover:

```
#content a.wpdm-download-link:link {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#content a.wpdm-download-link:hover {
    color: #aaffaa;
}
```